# Cant find "cloud functions admin" in firebase as role

Tags: firebase, flutterflow

Im following the oficial tutorial for flutterflow about how to setup firebase.

Video at 2:31: https://youtu.be/bG30uJ530-A?t=151

He says add a new role: `cloud functions admin`, but its not there. The closest one is `cloud functions service agent`

So I chose that...

Then he says to also add another role: `service account user`

Then when I try to savet I get the error:

```
IAM policy update failed
Only service accounts can be granted ServiceAgent roles as only service accounts can be service agents.
```

Any idea on whats the issue? And if the fact thast I added `cloud functions service agent` instead of `cloud functions admin` could be the problem?

Comment: I am having the same issue right now. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, but I've solved.

Goto Google Cloud Console to enable the Cloud Function API,

### Hope it help.

To enable an API for a project:
Go to the Google Cloud console API Library page. Go to the API Library page.
Select the Cloud project where you want to enable an API by performing one of the following: Click on a Cloud project under Select a recent project. ...
Click the API you want to enable. ...
Click the Enable button.